# Run a command on GUI (TTY7) on boot/login

Tags: tty, autostart

I am using an Xenial Xerus minimal Ubuntu install.

I want a command ("antimicro") to be run on boot/login (doesn't matter) to map my Bluetooth controller buttons to keyboard keys.
The farthest I could get is:

```
DISPLAY=":0" antimicro --hidden
```

Which does not work as a cron job, gdm postlogin commands or ~/.profile (gdm and Kodi not running), it seems to require a logged in terminal. It worked well when I execute it manually on tty1, it will display log and "occupies" the terminal until the application is closed.

I don't mind turning on auto login or disabling password etc. It's a HTPC running Kodi, and that's why I want it to be run automatically on each boot.

I am quite new on Linux and this may just be a stupid question, sorry if that's the case. I have tried my best to find information online.

EDIT: it's probably not a duplicate, none of the solutions worked.

Comment: You can NOT run a graphical command at boot. In cron you need to use the full path to commands.

Comment: Are you running lightdm with Kodi?

Comment: I will try the solutions given in the posts later, thank you for your help.

Comment: @XToro I'm using gdm with gnome, xfce and kodi installed.

Comment: Is it possible to autologin into tty1, run the command and switch to tty7?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script with the editor of your choice.

For my example, let's call it `btmap` and place it in `/home/username/scripts/`

Of course you would change `username` in the path with your actual username.

Put `DISPLAY=":0" antimicro` in the editor, save and close.

Open a terminal in the scripts folder where the `btmap` file is.  Type in `chmod 755 btmap` to make it executable.

Now `sudo su` and type password in if asked.

Type in `echo "/home/username/scripts/btmap" >> /etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default`

This will append your `Default` file with the execution of btmap.

Now reboot and see if it worked.

Comment: Does not work, seems like nothing has happened.

Comment: So your bluetooth controller doesn't connect?  Does the `DISPLAY=":0" antimicro` normally work for you when you type it in a terminal?  If not, you'll have to find the right command that makes it work for you.

Comment: My controller can connect and function as I want it to when executing the command manually. The only solution that "worked" is to put it in ~/.profile but that prevented gdm from loading.